# Getting Trying to get property of non-object error on the search suggestion

Tags: php, jquery, xml

Hi i am trying to create a search suggestion for a mobile app that i am creating. in it on searching to start the auto search starts giving suggestions. everything is working fine and i am also getting the output properly but the problem is i am getting a notice **Trying to get property of non-object** and i don't know what it actually is. So can someone help me out with this.

my code is

search.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function showResult(str) {
 if (str.length==0) { 
 document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
 return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else { 
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/donotdel/searchsuggestion.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
 <input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
 <div id="livesearch"></div>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

search.php

```
 <?php
 header ('Content-Type: application/xml');
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

 $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc->load("http://localhost/donotdel/d/categories.xml");

 $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('product');

 $q=$_GET["q"];

 if (strlen($q)>0) {
 $hint="";
 for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
 $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('name');
 if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
   if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
    if ($hint=="") {
      $hint= $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    } else {
      $hint=$hint . $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
  }
 }
 }
 }
 if ($hint=="") {
 $response="no suggestion";
 } else {
  $response=$hint;
 }
 echo $response;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The header in you PHP source is wrong. You output text currently, the output is not valid XML.

The error message should include an line number. In this line you're trying to access an object property of a variable,but the variable does not contain an object.

You're using DOM methods. Nothing wrong with that, but here is an easier way - use XPath:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Product One</name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product Two</name>
  </product>
</products>
XML;

$q = "product";

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$hint = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//product') as $product) {
  $text = $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(name)', $product);
  if (stristr($text, $q)) {
    $hint .= ' '.$text;
  }
}

var_dump(substr($hint, 1));
```

Output:

```
string(23) "Product One Product Two"
```

If you like to output an XML to the browser, use a second document to build it.

```
header ('Content-Type: application/xml');
...
$target= new DOMDocument();
$suggestions = $target->appendChild($target->createElement('suggestions'));

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//product') as $product) {
  $text = $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(name)', $product);
  if (stristr($text, $q)) {
    $suggestion = $suggestions->appendChild($target->createElement('suggestion'));
    $suggestion->appendChild($target->createTextNode($text));
  }
}

$target->formatOutput = true;
echo $target->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<suggestions>
  <suggestion>Product One</suggestion>
  <suggestion>Product Two</suggestion>
</suggestions>
```

Comment: what should be the header that i should be adding